# What should be use virtual or new in c#? What will be criteria to select among them?

Tags: c#, .net, virtual, virtual-functions

I am new to C# coding. I implemented following code and facing a warning.

```
class Base {
    public static Base Getinstance() {
        return new Base();
    }
}

class Derived : Base {
   // getting warning Derived.getInstance()' hides inherited member
   //'Base.getInstance()'. Use the new keyword if hiding was intended
   public static Derived Getinstance() {
        return new Derived();
   }
}
```

In order to remove the warning I have 2 options

1. use `virtual` in base class
2. write `new` in derived class
3. any other (please suggests if have anything else)

Which will be the right way to solve this warning?

Comment: Use `virtual` if you want to do proper inheritance, use `new` if you want to see the world burn.

Comment: Ready to set the world on fire

Comment: You have an apple and an orange. Which is the right to eat?

Comment: @zerkms He has an apple and an orange, and he asks how each tastes. That is totally legit.

Comment: Please do read about the keywords on MSDN, as it is explained pretty well.

Comment: @JeroenVannevel: too categorically. Sometimes `new` is quite applicable.

Comment: @zerkms The two are massively different; this question is an important one in terms of understanding C#'s object model.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is perfectly well explained in the official documentation: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173153.aspx

Comment: @DanPuzey I did not say it's not important. My analogy was about "they are different"

Comment: @YoryeNathan I cannot agree with you. The question is about which one to use without providing the requirements a solution must satisfy.

Comment: @zerkms Yes, as the question currently stands, you are correct.